# Using ngoninit doesn't load component

Tags: angular, ngoninit, angular17

I am trying to implement a image-slider.

I have a image-slider componenent and a component in which i want to display the image slider
I'd like to automatically slide through the images.

image-slider-component.html:

```
<div class="slides">
    <div
      class="slide"
      [ngStyle]="{
        'background-image': 'url(' + slides[currentSlide].url + ')',
        opacity: hidden ? 0 : 1,
        transition: 'opacity ' + animationSpeed + 'ms ease-in-out'
      }"
    ></div>
  
    @if (indicatorsVisible) {
    <div id="indicators">
      @for(slide of slides; track $index; ){
      <div
        (click)="jumpToSlide($index)"
        class="indicator"
        [ngClass]="{ active: $index == currentSlide }"
      ></div>
      }
    </div>
    }
  
    <button (click)="next()" class="nextButton">
      far
    </button>
    <button (click)="previous()" class="previousButton">
      back
    </button>
  </div>
```

image-slider-component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-slider',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './image-slider.component.html',
  styleUrl: './image-slider.component.scss',
})
export class ImageSliderComponent implements OnInit{

  @Input() slides: any[] = [];
  @Input() indicatorsVisible = true;
  @Input() animationSpeed = 500;
  @Input() autoPlay = true;
  @Input() autoPlaySpeed = 3000;
  currentSlide = 0;
  hidden = false;

  next() {
    let currentSlide = (this.currentSlide + 1) % this.slides.length;
    this.jumpToSlide(currentSlide);
  }

  previous() {
    let currentSlide =
      (this.currentSlide - 1 + this.slides.length) % this.slides.length;
    this.jumpToSlide(currentSlide);
  }

  jumpToSlide(index: number) {
    this.hidden = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.currentSlide = index;
      this.hidden = false;
    }, this.animationSpeed);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.autoPlay) {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.next();
      }, this.autoPlaySpeed);
    }
  }

}
```

more.component.html (i'd like to display the img-slider here)

```
<div
  style="
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
    gap: 20px;
  "
>
  <app-image-slider
    [indicatorsVisible]="false"
    [animationSpeed]="100"
    [slides]="slides"
    [autoPlay]="true"
    [autoPlaySpeed]="5"
  ></app-image-slider>

  <app-image-slider
    [indicatorsVisible]="true"
    [animationSpeed]="400"
    [slides]="slides"
    [autoPlay]="true"
    [autoPlaySpeed]="5"
  ></app-image-slider>
</div>
```

more.component.ts (here are the imgs that are used by the img-slider)

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { ImageSliderComponent } from '../about/components/image-slider/image-slider.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-more',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [    CommonModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ImageSliderComponent,],
  templateUrl: './more.component.html',
  styleUrl: './more.component.scss'
})
export class MoreComponent {
  
  slides: any[] = [
    {
      url: 'https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.webp',
      title: 'First Slide',
      description: 'test1',
    },
    {
      url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542831371-29b0f74f9713?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aHRtbHxlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D',
      title: 'Second Slide',
      description: 'test2',
    }
  ];

  
}
```

The page doesnt load:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktlu4.png)

If i remove the OnInit function aswell as the OnInit interface, the page is loading and i can switch through the images by the buttons i implemented, but the autoplay isn't working since I am not using the OnInit Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-high-slider',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './high-slider.component.html',
  styleUrl: './high-slider.component.scss'
})
export class HighSliderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  @Input() slides!: any[];
  @Input() indicatorsVisible!: boolean;
  @Input() animationSpeed!: number; // Milliseconds
  @Input() autoPlay!: boolean;
  @Input() autoPlaySpeed!: number; // Milliseconds

  currentSlide = 0;
  autoPlayInterval?: number; // Use a more specific type for the interval ID

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.autoPlay) {
      this.setupAutoPlay();
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.clearAutoPlay();
  }

  next(): void {
    this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide + 1) % this.slides.length;
  }

  previous(): void {
    this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide - 1 + this.slides.length) % this.slides.length;
  }

  jumpToSlide(index: number): void {
    this.currentSlide = index;
  }

  private setupAutoPlay(): void {
    // Check if running in the browser environment
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      this.autoPlayInterval = window.setInterval(() => this.next(), this.autoPlaySpeed);
    }
  }
  private clearAutoPlay(): void {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && this.autoPlayInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.autoPlayInterval);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

See that you don't clear the interval, so you early can have several intervals running.

Check also you have an interval like "5" milliseconds!!! and that when you execute jumpToSlide are "living" almost the autoplay and the another setTimeOut.

You need store in a variable your interval

```
interval:!any;
```

Create two functions: startInterval and clearInterval

```
startInterval()
{
   this.interval=setInterval(() => {
        this.next();
      }, this.autoPlaySpeed);
}

stopInterval()
{
   clearInterval(this.interval);
   this.interval= null;
}
```

Then,

1. you call to startInterval in ngOnInit
2. you call to stopInterval at start jumpToSlide  and startInterval at
   end jumToSlide
3. you call to stopInterval in ngOnDestroy
4. you can also call to stopInterval in a mouseEnter and a
   startInterval in a mouseOut

Comment: This doesn't work for me, page still doesn't load.